# UPDATE query is hanging

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the following query

```
UPDATE rec_analyst
           SET analyst_name = (SELECT DISTINCT min (LIQA_ANALYST_LAST_NAME)
                                 FROM LIQA
                                WHERE LIQA_ANALYST_ID = analyst_extern_id
                                      AND LIQA_TS_INSERT = '15.09.2011'

                               )
         WHERE analyst_provider_id = 4
```

Explain plan shows  costs of around 4000, but the database load is 100% and even after one hour this job is not ready.
Here the explain plan output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DESC                            |OBJECT NAME                    |COST| #    |BYTES  | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE STATEMENT, GOAL =ALL_ROWS|                               |  34| 16572| 331440|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  UPDATE                        |REC_ANALYST                    |    |      |       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   TABLE ACCESS FULL            |REC_ANALYST                    |  34| 16572|331440 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SORT AGGREGATE                |                               |    |      |24     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   TABLE ACCESS FULL            |REC_LIQA_LOAD_INQUIRY_ANALYST  |3965|1     |24     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I optimize it?

Comment: Can you post the explain plan? What are your indexed columns? BTW you don't need the DISTINCT as you have MIN in the subquery. Also qualify your date with a TO_DATE and format mask if LIQA_TS_INSERT is a DATE field.

Comment: Do you have an index on LIQA_TS_INSERT? If not you'll need one, assuming you have a of data. Likewise on analyst_provider_id and LIQA_ANALYST_ID. Best thing is look at execution plan and try the queries individually.

Comment: Possible problems: outdated database statistics (recalculate the statistics for the affected tables and try again) or locks caused by concurrent updates in other sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your DBA if it would be possible/advantagous to add an index on either (preferably both) of the following:

Table: rec_analyst column: analyst_provider_id 
Table: LIQA column: LIQA_TS_INSERT

Ideally there be PK/FK indexes on LIQA.analyst_id and rec_analyst.analyst_extern_id, not knowing your schema thought it's hard to say what indexes would benefit your system as a whole.

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
MERGE INTO rec_analyst ra
USING ( SELECT LIQA_ANALYST_ID analyst_id, MIN(LIQA_ANALYST_LAST_NAME) min_name
          FROM LIQA
         WHERE LIQA_TS_INSERT = '15.09.2011'
         GROUP BY LIQA_ANALYST_ID
      ) liqa_extract
   ON ( liqa_extract.analyst_id = ra.analyst_extern_id
        AND ra.analyst_provider_id = 4
      )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ra.analyst_name = liqa_extract.min_name;
```

Comment: Rationale: this way you prevent executing the liqa query as many times as there are rows in the rec_analyst table with provider_id 4.